# Erro na conversão de string para integer

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando cadastrar um cliente no BD interno do Android. Tenho um campo `String` onde coloco o telefone do usuário. Este campo eu faço a conversão para Integer utilizando o **`parseInt`**

```
newCliente.setFone(Integer.parseInt(foneDesc));
```

Se eu cadastrar no máximo dois números de telefone para o usuário ele aceita (foi o exemplo que usei). Mas seu eu digitar os 9 dígitos do telefone que é o correto ele dá erro:

> ```
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "4899984829"
>   at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
>   at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:378)
>   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
>   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
>   at artur.com.decorusfinal.cadastro.CadCliente$btGravar.onClick(CadCliente.java:68)
>   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
>   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ```

No erro ele dá diz que problema é na conversão

```
newCliente.setFone(Integer.parseInt(foneDesc));
```

[image: Erro na conversão]

Se não tivesse funcionando ele não deixaria nem eu cadastrar o usuário com apenas 2 números de telefone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Acontece o número que você está tentando converter é muito grande para ser int, converta para long...

Veja a tabela a seguir:

```
        tamanho                      mínimo                          máximo
signed    8 bit                        -128                            +127
signed   16 bit                     -32 768                         +32 767
signed   32 bit              -2 147 483 648                  +2 147 483 647
signed   64 bit  -9 223 372 036 854 775 808      +9 223 372 036 854 775 807
unsigned  8 bit                           0                            +255
unsigned 16 bit                           0                         +65 535
unsigned 32 bit                           0                  +4 294 967 295
unsigned 64 bit                           0     +18 446 744 073 709 551 615
```

Em java, conforme a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2)

```
      tamanho                      mínimo                          máximo
byte:   8 bit                        -128                            +127
short: 16 bit                     -32 768                         +32 767
int:   32 bit              -2 147 483 648                  +2 147 483 647
long:  64 bit  -9 223 372 036 854 775 808      +9 223 372 036 854 775 807
```

Veja que `int` é 32 bits então o máximo é 2 147 483 647 e você está tentando converter 4 899 984 829, você pode converter para `long` (64bits) isto resolve seu problema.

```
long l = Long.parseLong(foneDesc);
```

Mas como é um número de telefone há realmente a necessidade de converter para número?

Espero ter ajudado!!

Referencias:
[max value of integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15005226/6163123)

Comment: Acho que faltou um pedaço da tabela

Comment: @jbueno editei a resposta já com a outra tabela.

Comment: Agora sim. Boa resposta +1